# Adding values to HashMap

Tags: java, object-reference

I'm currently adding values to a `HashMap<String, SpriteSheetAnimation>`. I am also adding to the hashmap in the LoadFile method of my input class. When I add to the hashmap, which is part of the class GameObject that a reference is created for in the FileLoader. I alter the hashmap, adding keys and values to it, and everything is okay.

I then proceed to add the GameObject object to an objectManager where I store all of the objects for my game. When I reference the object in the ArrayList, however, the SpriteSheetAnimation value and the key of that value that I added in the file loader are no longer present. If I try to access them from within the FileLoader after adding them they are there though. I am a little confused. Is there possibly a scope issue going on here?

I've just realized something that may help you help me..(the System.out.println)

If I run this the component is not there when i try to fetch with the .toString

```
private void LoadControllableEntity(XMLEventReader eventReader, int x, int y)
{
    entities.ControllableEntity entity = new entities.ControllableEntity(x, y);
    entity.addComponent(new components.InputComponent(entity), "input");
    while(eventReader.hasNext())
    {
        try
        {

            XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();
            if(event.isEndElement())
            {
                if(event.asEndElement().getName().getLocalPart().equals("ControllableEntity"))
                {
                    break;
                }
            } else if(event.isStartElement())
            {
                String element = (String) event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart();
                if(element.equals("renderable"))
                {
                    entity.addComponent(new components.Renderable(entity), "renderer");
                }
                else if(element.equals("animationComponent"))
                {

                    entity.addComponent(getAnimationComponent(entity, event.asStartElement().getAttributes(), eventReader), "animation");

                }
            }
        } catch(XMLStreamException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(entity.getComponent("animation").toString());
        managers.ObjectManager.getInstance().addObject(entity);

    }

}
```

When I run this code though.. It can fetch the component fine(notice I've changed where I'm trying to get the component at.)

```
private void LoadControllableEntity(XMLEventReader eventReader, int x, int y)
{
    entities.ControllableEntity entity = new entities.ControllableEntity(x, y);
    entity.addComponent(new components.InputComponent(entity), "input");
    while(eventReader.hasNext())
    {
        try
        {

            XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();
            if(event.isEndElement())
            {
                if(event.asEndElement().getName().getLocalPart().equals("ControllableEntity"))
                {
                    break;
                }
            } else if(event.isStartElement())
            {
                String element = (String) event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart();
                if(element.equals("renderable"))
                {
                    entity.addComponent(new components.Renderable(entity), "renderer");
                }
                else if(element.equals("animationComponent"))
                {

                    entity.addComponent(getAnimationComponent(entity, event.asStartElement().getAttributes(), eventReader), "animation");
                    System.out.println(entity.getComponent("animation").toString());
                }
            }
        } catch(XMLStreamException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        managers.ObjectManager.getInstance().addObject(entity);

    }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Post relevant short code to begin with. BTW Welcome to stack overflow

Comment: @Aniket  I have added some code.. I think it is something that I am not understanding pertaining to object references.. I hope you can help!

Comment: @MouseEvent I posted some code.. I hope it can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your first code-snippet is that you retrieve and print the `animation` entity on *every* pass through the loop — even before you add that entity — whereas in your second code-snippet you only retrieve and print it immediately after adding the entity, so obviously it doesn't have that problem.

I think you want to change this:

```
        System.out.println(entity.getComponent("animation").toString());
        managers.ObjectManager.getInstance().addObject(entity);

    }
```

to this:

```
    }

    System.out.println(entity.getComponent("animation").toString());
    managers.ObjectManager.getInstance().addObject(entity);
```

That is, I think you want those last few steps to be performed after the `while`-loop has completed, rather than doing it at the end of each iteration.

Comment: That was part of my problem. I was also adding the animation to the entity in the getAnimationComponent() method, which I think was also causing problems. Thanks!

Comment: @CodyShort If this was the correct answer, please "upvote" it (click the up-pointing triangle above left; the "accept" it by clicking the checkmark.